# In Bicep what is replacement for copyIndex() in json : json to bicep converter not working properly

Tags: json, azure-bicep

"name": "[concat('storage', copyIndex())]",

Creates these names:
storage0
storage1
storage2

what to do in case to  achieve the same in bicep. Json to bicep converter not producing the result correctly.

Here is use case ::
var :
"firewallPublicIPNamePrefix": "[concat(parameters('firewallName'), 'PublicIP')]",

param :
"numberOfFirewallPublicIPAddresses": {
"type": "int",
"defaultValue": 1,
"minValue": 1,
"maxValue": 100,
"metadata": {
"description": "Number of public IP addresses for the Azure Firewall"
}
},
"firewallName": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "AzFirewall",
"metadata": {
"description": "The name of the Azure Firewall."
}
}

changes :

```
  {
    "condition": "[parameters('createDnatRuleCollection')]",
    "comments": "Azure Firewall Policy NAT Rule Collection",
    "name": "[variables('firewallPolicyDefaultDnatRuleCollectionGroupName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/ruleCollectionGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[variables('firewallPolicyId')]",
      "[variables('firewallId')]",
      "[variables('firewallPolicyDefaultNetworkRuleCollectionGroupId')]",
      "[variables('Vm1NicId')]",
      "[variables('Vm2NicId')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "priority": "100",
      "ruleCollections": [
        {
          "name": "VirtualMachineNatRules",
          "ruleCollectionType": "FirewallPolicyNatRuleCollection",
          "priority": "300",
          "action": {
            "type": "Dnat"
          },
          "rules": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('Vm1Name'), '-Rdp-Nat-Rule')]",
              "ruleType": "NatRule",
              "sourceAddresses": [
                "*"
              ],
              "destinationAddresses": [
                "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', if(equals(parameters('numberOfFirewallPublicIPAddresses'), 1), variables('firewallPublicIPNamePrefix'), concat(variables('firewallPublicIPNamePrefix'), add(copyIndex(), 1))))).ipAddress]"
              ],
              "destinationPorts": [
                "4001"
              ],
              "ipProtocols": [
                "TCP"
              ],
              "translatedAddress": "[reference(variables('Vm1NicId')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
              "translatedPort": "22"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('Vm2Name'), '-Rdp-Nat-Rule')]",
              "ruleType": "NatRule",
              "sourceAddresses": [
                "*"
              ],
              "destinationAddresses": [
                "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', if(equals(parameters('numberOfFirewallPublicIPAddresses'), 1), variables('firewallPublicIPNamePrefix'), concat(variables('firewallPublicIPNamePrefix'), add(copyIndex(), 1))))).ipAddress]"
              ],
              "destinationPorts": [
                "4002"
              ],
              "ipProtocols": [
                "TCP"
              ],
              "translatedAddress": "[reference(variables('Vm2NicId')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
              "translatedPort": "22"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

how to convert this "destinationAddresses" part to bicep?

Comment: could you paste relevant part of your arm template please? you may have few options with bicep.

Comment: @Thomas, I updated the question with my use case. plz share how to tackle this situation.

Comment: so you are trying to select the ip address of a public IP resource ? Or you are selecting all the ips based on the parameter `ip` ? and all the public ip names start with the value of the variable `fpnp` ?

Comment: From your arm, not sure to understand if you are trying to select one ip or multiple ?

Comment: it would be great if you could share the whole arm template (if not too big) that would help to understand the deployment context.

Comment: Also are you creating multiple ruleCollection ?

Comment: entire template is too big, I have pasted one entire block and required params and var.

Comment: In your template, where are you defining the `copy` object. I dont see any iteration here ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your example in bicep, you'd do this;

```
resource storageAcct 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for i in range(0, 2): {
  name: 'storage${i}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}]
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops

If the bicep decompile from json isn't working properly for your Arm template, then consider raising an issue on the bicep project. https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues

For more complex scenarios (I notice you've added IP Addresses to the question), i'd look at the Bicep support in 0.17 for some [IP CIDR capabilities](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/3975#issuecomment-1537513857)
I think the `cidrHost('10.144.3.0/24', i)` function would simplify your current logic.

Comment: I 'm not sure if it can be utilized in my situation. I have updated my use case in question.

Comment: I'd updated my answer to address the IP point.